# What are the parameters to collect after the performance testing

Tags: performance, load-testing, performance-testing, performancecounter, loadrunner

I know this may be a repeat of the questions but I started using the WebPerformanceTest and LoadTest in my web projects.I could run the WebPerformanceTest and Loadttest.

Now what are the parameters/statistics that I need to share with the Dev team or Busniess team?I think of these..But it would be great if somoeone share what are the other parameters I might have to consider sharing..

1.No.of users the application can support

2.Reposne time what the application can give under the sustainable load

Comment: Is your question related to LoadRunner?

Comment: its not specific to a tool I am asking this abt.In general what parameters/statistics you want to collect ?

Answer (score 3):

following things you can consider for sharing,

1. if SLA's are mentioned by Dev team or stakeholders and if your performance test shows that the web application is not matching those SLA's then you can share that
2. Next question comes in your and their mind is why? (try finding out which part/tier is taking most time or a bottleneck). This can be done by analyzing logs or use profiler which will give you costly things,slow compnonents
3. Next question is job of performance engineer (how to resolve them and improve the performance of my application). If you know application very well then try tuning it and get the improvement results after tuning which should be shared with Dev team or stakeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum number of users may be confusing if you do not limit response time. For 100ms requests 10 simultaneos users mean 100 rps (requests per second) and for 10s requests 100 simultaneous users mean only 10 rps.
If you use simple hit-based testing (e.g. testing single page or specific request performance) it could be better to use rps metric instead.

For response time - mean time could be confusing as well, especially in case of high variance of response time, it's better to provide response time for some percentiles.

I.e. 50% in 50ms, 75% in 55 ms, 90% in 60 ms, 95% in 70 ms, 99% in 90 ms and 100% in 10 sec. With average time of 150 ms. For some services 150 ms is very good, but about 1% of really slow answers is unacceptable and you hardly can find that problem using just mean and medium response time.

Also, in my experience, collecting resource usage stats (cpu, memory, I/O intensity and network usage) is very helpful for determining bottlenecks (i.e. service slow-down due to high I/O because of insufficient amount of memory for caches).

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking the right question?

For me a big part of load and performance testing is deciding what my customer wants to learn about the system being tested. There is an element of "what data can I show the customer?" but that is based on interpreting what they ask for. The customer may not know what to ask, your job as a tester is to understand what the customer wants and provide them with the answers they want.

The two topics you list show how the system appears to its users: when it will break and how fast it responds. There are several variations on those factors based on rate-of-change of user load and on duration of the test.

Other factors include the performance of the various parts of the server computers that are being tested. Visual Studio load tests can collect performance data from other computers while the test runs. So they can monitor the web server(s), database server(s), application server(s) and so on. On each of these servers data about CPU and memory usage, SQL and IIS performance, and many more can be collected. All this data can be compared (most easily via graphs) against user load, error rates and transaction times to determine which parts of the system have plenty of headroom, which are busy and where the bottlenecks occur. Monitoring all this data may also reveal threshold warnings from the various servers, they should be checked against the Microsoft documentation and, perhaps, other sources to determine whether they are adversely affecting system performance and whether they should be investigated in more detail.

These and many other ideas are possible but it all goes back to working out what your customer wants to learn.

The [same question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79266091-5db2-4209-b76a-c794f620ec42/what-are-the-parameters-to-collect-after-the-performance-testing?forum=vstest) was asked on another forum and the above words are almost identical to the answer I posted there.

Answer (score 0):

You can furnish following details to your clients:

1. Response Time
2. Hits per Second
3. Throughput
4. Connections Per Second
5. First Time to buffer
6. Number of Errors
7. Transactions Graph
8. CPU, Memory, and Disk Utilization
9. Network Utilization (if applicable)
10. Number of database inserts/updates/deletes records

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply have no (or exceedingly poor) requirements and you don't have a great depth in the field of performance testing and engineering.    As far as what to collect

Before the test:

- Full load profile of business functions that make up the load.
- Documentation of each business function.   Items to time within each business function.
- Expected response times for each of the timed business functions
- Pay special attention to think times and iteration pacing
- Web logs from the current system so you can objectively measure how many people are on the system at any given time, not how many sessions are alive and have not yet timed out.
- Test Environment with some defined match level to the production environment to scale your load appropriately.

In the test

- Response times matched to the timing of the business functions on the requirements / user stories
- Other enumerated datapoints for requirements (hits, volume returned, etc...)
- A measurement of any finite resource in the system under test for bottleneck identification for slow response times.   You can start at the top level (CPU, DISK, MEMORY,  NETWORK) and work your way down through those stats as you find a resource constriction at the top level.

Post Test:

- Executive overview: Did you hit the requrements (YES|NO)
- Detailed data: response times, monitor peaks
- Analysis: Where is the likely bottleneck holding your back

If you are attempting to represent human behavior then under no circumstance should you eliminate think time.   Think time, or time between requests on an individual session, is baked into the definition of the client-server model and as you reduce it to zero your test becomes less and less a predictor of what will happen in production

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it is based on the benchmark that you want to achieve with the given hardware and environment.
Following are the key parameters

- No.of concurrent users (manual and system threads)
- Load of transactional and existing data
- Response time (typically page)
- Throughput  Utilization of CPU, Memory and Disk IOs and Network
- Bandwidth(applicable where there is an integration with peripheral
  systems )
- Success percentage